# Flask ImportError causing 500 error, works on local

Tags: python, flask

Application works on local using `python run.py` but when deployed to Ubuntu VPS with Apache, it gives a 500 error.

Apache Logs return:

```
File "/var/www/ssapi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 28, in <module>, referer: http://api.soundshelter.net/
[Fri Jun 03 04:20:47.336788 2016] [:error] [pid 26915] [client 64.245.52.2:57465]     from .config import ConfigAttribute, Config, referer: http://api.soundshelter.net/
[Fri Jun 03 04:20:47.336819 2016] [:error] [pid 26915] [client 64.245.52.2:57465] ImportError: No module named config, referer: http://api.soundshelter.net/
```

Directory Structure

[image]

init.py

```
from flask import Flask
import config
from . import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
```

api.py

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify,abort, make_response

#http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/9/
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache

import collections

#database connect
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import json
import sys


import sys, os
sys.path.append('/var/www/ssapi')
import config

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = config.user
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = config.password
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = config.database
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = config.host
....
....
....
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=False,host='0.0.0.0')
```

I don't understand why it works on local but not deployed.

config.py definitely exists on VPS

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @tmthydvnprt How to stop the error :-)

Comment: You should add a little bit of an explanation or narrative to your post rather than just error logs and code...

Comment: @tmthydvnprt updated

Comment: You seem to be missing a `__init__.py` in the root directory. You might want it if you are importing things from that level, though I don't know why it would work locally without it

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. I have tried adding the same __init__.py file to the root directory but still the same error.

Comment: When you deploy, does the `config.py` file exist? I see you have a template, so that leads me to believe you have modified the template and have not committed the config you have locally

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes the config.py file is deployed in the root directory (same as screenshot in the question)

Comment: Not really what to tell you otherwise, but the errors say different `No module named config`. Although it also says the error originated in Flask at `site-packages/flask/app.py`, so maybe try reinstalling Flask?

Answer (score 1):

Re-install Flask fixed this. Thanks @cricket_007